# Dissolve with expression in QGIS

Tags: dissolve, qgis-2.18

I have a shapefile with polygons containing UK postcode units, example SL1 1AA. I want to dissolve these into postcode sectors,example SL1 1.

[image]

I can use this expression in the filter to get all those postcode units in one sector and dissolve that as the image above.

`LIKE 'SL1 1%%'`

What i want to do is apply a similar expression with dissolve altering the expression to a `regex` so it dissolves into SL1 1, SL1 2 etc.

I have an idea how i could tackle this in postgis but wanted to see if i could do this with the QGIS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you want this to work anywhere in the UK, there are [several formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postcodes_in_the_United_Kingdom)

the following regex :-

```
[A-Z]{1,2}\d+[A-Z]?\s\d
```

should match the 6 possible patterns

- **EC1A 1**BB
- **W1A 0**AX
- **M1 1**AE
- **B33 8**TH
- **CR2 6**XH
- **DN55 1**PT

The following works, assuming your field is called **pcd**.

You can use the `regexp_substr()` function in QGIS expressions, but this won't work unless

- there is an outer group (i.e. brackets around the whole expression)
- backslashes are doubled (to escape them)

You can use this expression to extract the bit you want

```
regexp_substr("pcd",'([A-Z]{1,2}\\d+[A-Z]?\\s\\d)')
```

I found a few which didn't match, I'm not sure where I got the data from (either OS or ONS; the latter includes lots of expired postcodes which may explain some discrepancies)

A simpler way (and probably faster too, with large datasets) is to simply find the space and take everything up to and including the character after it

```
 left("pcd" ,strpos("pcd",' ')+1)
```

Comment: Thank you, opted for the regex which works well on the official OS set. I'm running whole of Eng Wales so will test the two approaches

Answer (score 3):

Open field calculator and make a new field with the expression `left(postcode, 5)` Then use the dissolve tool. In the tools' form, uncheck "dissolve all" and use the new field to dissolve by.

Comment: Thank you, i used this in conjunction with @Steven Kays answer